# MySQL per-connection timezone not populating CURRENT_TIMESTAMP correctly

Tags: mysql, timezone, utc

I’m trying to set the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP TO UTC right before inserting the row into the DB.  From what I’ve read, this is how you can do it per-connection.

My server's timezone is EST (+5:00).

I do the following while debugging:

1. SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; Store this guy to use when debugging.
2. SET TIME_ZONE = '-00:00';
3. SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; Store this guy to use when debugging.
4. As of now, I’d expect my database connection’s time_zone to be UTC.
5. INSERT/UPDATE record as per usual.

I then pass the two timestamps back to my page just to see what they are.

First one is defaulted to EST: `[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] => 2016-12-15 14:01:52`

Second is UTC as set by the query: `[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] => 2016-12-15 19:01:52`

However, the record in the DB has the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP of 2016-12-15 14:01:52 (EST).

No idea why!

---

I am using Sequel Pro to view my DB.
Seems that Sequel Pro converts timestamps to local time.

The record returns via SQL as desired/expected:

`2016-12-15 19:46:50`

Sequel pro displays:

`2016-12-15 14:46:50`

So... this leaves me a tad upset with my choice of DB application in how it handles timezones.  If anyone thinks this is not the actual issue by all means let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP` data types are *always* stored in MySQL in UTC. There's no way to store it with reference to some other time zone except by offsetting it. It's translated, whenever it is rendered, using the current `time_zone` setting. There's no way to view the *actual* value of a stored `TIMESTAMP` except by setting the `time_zone` setting to `UTC` or `-00:00` or some equivalent, then reading it.

So,

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Halifax';  
SELECT @a := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;   --> 2016-12-15 15:49:49
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
SELECT @a, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;     --> 2016-12-15 15:49:49 2016-12-15 19:49:49
SET time_zone = 'America/Halifax';
SELECT @a, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;     --> 2016-12-15 15:49:49 2016-12-15 15:49:49
```

In the second line of that sequence, the current timestamp is rendered to a text string variable @a, in the context of Atlantic Standard Time.

In the fourth the text string is displayed, then the current timestamp rendered in the context of UTC.

`DATETIME` and `DATE` data are stored verbatim,  with out reference to time zone settings.

Comment: This makes total sense.  However, I have found that issue seems to be with the application in which I use to view my DB data (Sequel Pro).  The record returns from a SELECT statement as expected, yet shows differently in the application.